# How to dynamically pass MS Dynamics token to REST API setup in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

MS Dynamics 365 has exposed two REST APIs in order to get to the data.  The first API is an URL that returns a token.  I need to dynamically pass the token as header to the second REST API and pull the actual data. Can we use Logic Apps or Azure data factory to accomplish this?  If yes, can you please provide the steps to accomplish this?  Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Are you trying to query data out of CRM from an external service?

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps has a native connector to the D365 Common Data Service, and it can be triggered using a REST call, so it could in effect replace the need for the native REST API, but it would not be my first choice because it will add some overhead (delay) to your round-trip depending on whether the Logic App has been used lately.